# knitr - error when importing python module

Tags: python, r, knitr, sys, reproducible-research

I am having trouble when running the python engine in knitr. I can import some modules but not others. For example I can import numpy but not pandas.

`{r, engine='python'}
import pandas`

I get the error.

```
Quitting from lines 50-51 (prepayment.Rmd) 
Error in (knit_engines$get(options$engine))(options) : 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
Calls: <Anonymous> ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning message:
running command ''python'  -c 'import pandas' 2>&1' had status 1 
Execution halted
```

It must be something to do with system path and where I am pointing.

Normally in IPython i use

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/directory/')
```

To add paths. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Are you trying to use `sys` with knitr as well?

Comment: So I first tried to use sys with knitr and it didn't work like it would work with IPython so then I tried something more simple like importing pandas and that didn't work. But I was able to import other packages e.g. numpy...  Any idea why?

Comment: Are the sources for your packages in different places? You could use the R equivalents, take a look at `Sys.getenv("path")`.

Comment: Can you post a hierarchical description of your packages?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
{python engine.path="C:/anaconda/python.exe"}
import pandas
```

change `C:/anaconda/python.exe` to your `python` path.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too, in Atom.

Check to make sure the two files are in the same directory. Put them in the same folder or path.

Then, go into Terminal or Command Line and type

`cd Downloads`

(or whatever large directory the files are in). Then, type in smaller folder like: `cd _____`, such as `cd animals`. There, you can open the one file that you want to have the other file import to by typing `python3 -i ____.py` (file name). Make sure the file has `from ___(master file) import *` and you can run the code in terminal.

This should work. The problem is you can't import by running the code. Instead, you have to link the two using terminal or command line.

Comment: Yup, got that. Thanks! ;)